# Simple Keyboard Hook to Start/Stop Timer in VB.Net 2010

Tags: timer, vb.net-2010, keyhook

I making a program that needs to be able to respond to the key press of `Ctrl + '` (that's control + apostrophe) even when the program does not have focus.

The `Ctrl + '` will be used to start and stop a timer.

The code would be something like (just some psuedo-code for my example):

```
On Ctrl + ' KeyPress
  If TimerStart = False

    Timer.Start()
    TimerStart = True

  Else

    Timer.Stop()
    TimerStart = False

End If
```

I have read that using a keyboard hook is the way to go and this is my preferred method, however I struggle to even understand the tutorials I read and am having trouble with the virtual key codes.

I found a decent tutorial [here](http://www.developer.com/net/net/article.php/11087_2193301_3/Managing-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hooks-in-VB-NET.htm), but my lack of knowledge makes it hard for me to translate that into what I need.

Any help or an example specific to what I need would be very beneficial for me. This is the last thing I need to code to finish my program and I feel a more specific example, to my needs, would help me to break down and understand this better.